# Javafx problem while creating a simple taskmanager application. The problem lies in MainController class and viewTaskController class i think

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

So what is happening is when i click on view tasks button it takes me to view tasks scene but does not show any list of tasks.

Main.java

```
package com.example.task_manager;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();
    }
}
```

TaskManager class

```
package com.example.task_manager;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class TaskManager {

    private ObservableList<Task> tasks;

    public TaskManager(){

        tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tasks.add(new Task("Task1",true));
        tasks.add(new Task("Task2",false));
        tasks.add(new Task("Task3",true));
    }

    public void add(Task task)
    {
        tasks.add(task);
    }
    public void deleteTask(Task task)
    {
        tasks.remove(task);
    }

    public void edit(int index, Task task)
    {
        tasks.set(index, task);
    }

    public ObservableList<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }
}
```

Task class

```
package com.example.task_manager;

public class Task {
    private String title;
    private boolean status;

    public Task(String title, boolean status) {
        this.title = title;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

MainController class

```
package com.example.task_manager;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Button addBtn,viewBtn,deleteBtn,editBtn;
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeLabel,optionsLabel;

    private Parent root;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;

    private TaskManager taskManager;

    public MainController()
    {
        taskManager = new TaskManager();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        taskManager.add(new Task("Task4",false));
    }
    public void viewTasks(ActionEvent event)
    {
//        System.out.println("Viewing tasks");
        try{
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("viewTasks.fxml"));
            root = fxmlLoader.load();

            // Access the controller of the loaded viewTasks.fxml
            viewTaskController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

            // Pass the TaskManager instance to the viewTaskController using setTaskManager
            controller.setTaskManager(taskManager);

            stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

viewTaskController class

```
package com.example.task_manager;


import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class viewTaskController {

    @FXML
    private Button back;
    @FXML
    private Label title;
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scroll;
    @FXML
    private ListView<Task> listview;
    private Parent root;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;

    private TaskManager taskManager;

    public void setTaskManager(TaskManager taskManager)
    {
        this.taskManager = taskManager;
        System.out.println("Setting taskmanager");
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        if(taskManager!=null){
            System.out.println("Not null");
            ObservableList<Task> tasks = taskManager.getTasks();
            listview.setItems(tasks);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Null");
            TaskManager temp = new TaskManager();
            ObservableList<Task> tasks = temp.getTasks();
            listview.setItems(tasks);
        }
    }
    public void backToMainMenu(ActionEvent event)
    {
        try{
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With the debug output statements im getting

```
Sept 03, 2023 11:34:41 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 20.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 17.0.8
Sept 03, 2023 11:34:42 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 20.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 17.0.8
Null
Setting taskmanager
```

If you guys need the fxml files i can share them also. Please help me find out why this is happening

Comment: When `ViewTaskController:initialize` executes, `taskManager` has the default value, `null`. It looks like [_Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187963/230513) may help. Also consider adopting Java naming conventions.

Comment: Your `setTaskManager()` method needs to update the `listview` with the new task manager’s list of tasks.